# Can't Sync Github with Visual Studio

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am having a hard time syncing vs code with github.  A while back I signed up for github with one username and password and synced vs code with github (although I'm not sure it worked properly back then either).

Today, though, I needed to start a new github account, which I did.  However, when I tried to push changes up to github, I kept getting a permissions denied error.  It seemed that vs code was using my old username.

This is the message that I get:

```
remote: Permission to NEW_USER_NAME/acf-admin-menus.git denied to OLD_USER_NAME.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NEW_USER_NAME/REPO_NAME/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41867), it seems that it has nothing to do with vscode and that you have to update your credentials saved in git.

Comment: Thanks -- that helped.  I updated my credentials and it now works.  I followed the advice on this page:  https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/